# Handling incorrect method (controller) parameters In Codeiginiter or other MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm codeing in codeigintier but this question equally applies to any MVC framework.

How do I abstract the logic for determining if a parameter for a controller method is valid across mutlple methods that take some of the same parameters?

**EDIT: More detail**

For example in the application I'm building at the moment there are multiple 'sites' and nearly all the data in different tables belongs to a site and a user can only view a subset of the sites. So lots of my methods start `method($site_id,...)` so it would be really nice if I was able to have a pre_controller hook which could look at the parameters for the methods and detect if there was a $site_id in the parameters, and if there was check the permissions.

The problem is that not all the methods in those controllers will all have a $site_id parameter, so I cannot do the checking automatically in the constructor of my extension of CI_Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CodeIgniter one way of going about abstracting the logic is to create a super class as such:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //...do stuff...
    }
    //...do stuff...
}


/* End of file MY_Controller.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Controller.php */
```

All your controllers that you want to share the same logic should then extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller

Now in your MY_Controller you can create functions to "handle incorrect parameters across multiple methods".

**UPDATE**

Your controller function params are coming from your route. e.g. `mydomain.com/mycontroller/myfunction/param1/param2/` would go to the `mycontroller` `public function myfunction($param1, $param2)`

`$site_id` is just your variable naming. You can't tell what it's named and even if you could i doubt it's a good idea to based any logic on how you name your variables.

A simple way is just to explicitly call the validating function (stored once in your base controller, a library or a helper) in each controller's function that require it, that gives you fine grain control.

**UPDATE**

```
Extending the controller would only work if my parameters were the same for each method. I'd like to detect automatically the parameters and perform checks. I suppose a call to a helper might be the best I can do, but Id just like to be able to completely abstract it away from the method. I suppose one option would be to have an array of which controllers and methods have $site_id as their first parameter and have a pre_controller hook to do the checking. But this would mean keeping the array up-to-date which kind of defeats the object of my question which is to make things as DRY as possible!
```

Generally, to gain automation you must give up flexibly and follow conventions.
so to not go the "use helper" way and to go the auto detect way... create your own convention.

in your base controller use $this->uri->segment(n) to check if a certain URL pattern exist, if it does you know that the site_id param is incoming and that you can run automatic validation on it.

Comment: mikes way is also valid - you can use CI libraries or helpers to keep your shared parameter validation logic.

Comment: Yes, I've extended the CI_Controller to define some default methods such as `delete()`. But not all the methods will have the parameters in the same order, or at all... see my edit to the question above with more detail

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right - I was just wanting to be too lazy, but in fact my code will be a lot clearer if I just call a helper function, which in fact could be made very simple by passing just func_get_args() and an array of strings telling the validation helper which arguments were which

Answer (score 0):

Extend the same controller and do some validation in a preDispatch or init method.

Or abstract the validation into a controller-helper and use it in both controllers.

Comment: Extending the controller would only work if my parameters were the same for each method. I'd like to detect automatically the parameters and perform checks. I suppose a call to a helper might be the best I can do, but Id just like to be able to completely abstract it away from the method. I suppose one option would be to have an array of which controllers and methods have $site_id as their first parameter and have a pre_controller hook to do the checking. But this would mean keeping the array up-to-date which kind of defeats the object of my question which is to make things as DRY as possible!

Comment: @rgvcorley I don't know enough about CI but you might be able to hook into the Router's shutdown routine after it's determined the controller/action and use a plugin to do some validation before it dispatches.

Comment: I know I can hook into the core just before the controller method is called, but I still don't have a way of knowing which method parameters are which, since I cannot use reflection to find the parameter variable names. I guess one option would be to use ranges for all my db ids, but this seems crazy and would cause problems with a url that contained an int that wasn't actually a record id